# How to deal with implicit dependency (e.g C++ include) for incremental build in custom Skylark rule

Tags: bazel

## Problem

I wonder how to inform bazel about dependencies unknown at declaration time, but known at build time (a.k.a implicit dependencies, dynamic dependencies, ...). For instance when compiling C++ sources, the .cpp source file will depends on some header files and this information is not available when writing the BUILD file. It needs to be retrieve at build time. Whatever is the solution to get the information (dry-run, generating depfile, parsing stdout), it needs to be done at build time and the information need to be retrieved to bazel build graph.

Since skylark does not allow to do I/O, for instance to read a generated depfile or to parse stdout result containing a dependency list, I have no clue on how to deal with it.

Behind implicit dependencies, I am looking for correct incremental build.

## Example

To experiment this problem I have created a simple tool, `just_a_tool.exe` which takes an input file, read a list of file from it, and concatenate the content of all these file to an output file.

*command line example:*

```
just_a_tool.exe --input input.txt --depfile dep.d output.txt
```

dep.d contains the list of all the read files.

#### Issue

If I change the content of test1.txt, test2.txt, or test3.txt, bazel does not rebuild output.txt file. Of course, because it does not know there were dependencies.

#### Example files

*just_a_tool.bzl*

```
def _impl(ctx):
    exec_path = "C:/Code/JustATool/just_a_tool.exe"

    for f in ctx.attr.source.files:
        source_path = f.path
    output_path = ctx.outputs.out.path

    dep_file = ctx.actions.declare_file("dep.d")

    args = ["--input", source_path, "--dep_file", dep_file.path, output_path]

    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs=[ctx.outputs.out, dep_file], 
        executable=exec_path,
        inputs=ctx.attr.source.files,
        arguments=args
    )

jat_convert = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        "source" : attr.label(mandatory=True, allow_files=True, single_file=True)
    },
    outputs = {"out": "%{name}.txt"}
)
```

*BUILD*

```
load("//tool:just_a_tool.bzl", "jat_convert")

jat_convert(
    name="my_output",
    source=":input.txt"
)
```

*input.txt*

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
```

## Goal

I want to do correct and fast incremental build for the following situation:

- Generate reflection data from C++ sources, this custom tool execution depends on header file included in my source files.
- Use a internal tool to build asset file which can include other files
- Run a custom preprocessor on my shaders allowing a #include feature

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bazel's extension language doesn't support creating actions with a dynamic set of inputs, where this set depends on the output of a previous action. In other words, custom rules cannot run an action, read the action's output, then create actions with those inputs or update (or prune the set of) inputs of already created actions.

Instead I suggest adding attribute(s) to your rule where the user can declare the set of files that the sources may include. I call this "the universe of headers". The actions you create depend on this user-defined universe, so the set of action inputs is completely defined. Of course this means these actions potentially depend on more files than the cpp files, which they process, include.

This approach is analogous to how the `cc_*` rules work: a file in `cc_*.srcs` can include other files in the `srcs` of the same rule and from `hdrs` of dependencies, but nothing else. Thus the union of `srcs` + `hdrs` of (direct & transitive) dependencies defines the universe of header files that a cpp file may include.

Comment: I am curious on how incremental build work?
If I have a big library with hundred of .cpp sources and hundred of .h header file, if I follow your method, each .cpp will depends on all the .h files. So changing one line in a header file will trigger the rebuild of all the .cpp, instead of the one which really include the header. Am I correct?

Comment: Actually I have checked the behavior of native cc_binary and it is able to do a correct incremental build. If I change a header file, only .cpp which include this header will be recompiled.

Comment: I also noticed cl.exe use the /showInclude flags which display the list of include used for compiling. Bazel source refer everywhere to parse_showIncludes, and I have even found a rules\cpp\IncludeScanner.java file inside of the bazel source code.

I may have misunderstood your answer, but it seems the behavior or cc_binary is different from what you think.

My concern about implicit dependencies here is to be able to do fast and correct incremental build in skylark.

Comment: You're asking great questions! :) Indeed the native C++ rules perform "include scanning" and "`.d` file parsing", exactly for the sake of better incrementality, so Bazel won't recompile `.cc` files if neither them nor their transitive closure of included headers have changed. As far as I know, only the C++ rules do this kind of action input pruning. That said, unfortunately Bazel has no API to allow this in skylark rules, which is why I carefully (but not carefully enough ;) chose my words as "Bazel's extension language doesn't support" this.

Comment: Asking more folks to chime in: [@Lukacs](https://github.com/lberki), do you think action templates could help here, and if so, is that API available to custom rules?

Comment: That's my big concern with Bazel. Until skylark is powerful enough to implement native 
rule with the same behavior and the same speed, I think bazel cannot be considered as a "general, 
agnostic, cross-language, cross-tool, build system" yet.

Comment: In the game industry we deal with heavy asset pipeline, custom processing tool and custom build process. 
Usually this problem is solve with hybrid solution using several build system (as msbuild, cmake, ninja) and some script on top
of it to glue everything together. But it is far from perfect.


I am looking for general build system, the one to rule them all. I still did not find it. I hope bazel can become it one day.

Comment: I agree with you that Bazel is not yet perfect at solving this task, but I want to point out that it can already do it reasonably well: you get good incrementality if the libraries are fine-grained, even if they specify supersets of inputs. Furthermore if an action produces the same output(s) as before, then Bazel won't rerun the downstream action (unless its other inputs changed). What I mean to say is, consider giving Bazel a second thought, because it can already do well even without a perfectly lean dependency set.

Comment: I was hoping maybe a miracle solution from your "action templates" word ! :-)

Comment: Changing an include in a very low-level library will trigger the compilation of all the .cpp of this library and all the libraries on top of it (because they can potential include any header of the low-level library). If the .cpp did not change I will only save the downstream action: the link time.

Comment: But my problem is even not compiling C++ where I can use native rule, it is more about my asset pipeline where any asset could include any other asset. I love Bazel and the concept of Bazel, I am eager to use it, it just does not fit my need yet. But I am looking forward :-)

Comment: Btw, do you know if this kind of skylark design issue is under consideration? Is it plan to replace native per skylark rule one day?

Comment: "If the .cpp did not change I will only save the downstream action: the link time." -- Yes, that's unfortunately true if anything can include anything else.

Comment: "Btw, do you know if this kind of skylark design issue is under consideration?" -- dynamic deps? I don't know. "Is it plan to replace native per skylark rule one day?" -- yes! Well, it's more of a long-term vision and direction we want to go towards, but currently unrealistic. It's hard to tell how realistically that'll happen within the next $LONG_TIMESPAN.

Comment: "But my problem is even not compiling C++ where I can use native rule, it is more about my asset pipeline where any asset could include any other asset." -- yes, I hear you :-/ If anything can include anything else, then as I see it the only good solution would be something like `.d` file parsing, and sadly that's not available as a general-purpose mechanism. "I love Bazel and the concept of Bazel, I am eager to use it, it just does not fit my need yet. But I am looking forward :-)" -- i'm really happy to hear that :)

Comment: I am glad to know the vision is to replace native rules by Skylark rule, that mean one day this problem will be solved !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160754/discussion-between-dragnalith-and-laszlo).